# As per Hinduism, where can married lady wear Sindoor?

Tags: women, marriage, tradition

Per Hinduism, where can married lady wear Sindoor?

What if the lady has bangs, i.e. no obvious part in the hair.

Comment: I think bangs should not be a problem since sindoor should start from forehead and goes back to head.

Comment: Sindoor can be applied on the forehead (middle). Based on one's preferences, once can apply a long or short sindoor.

Answer (score 4):

The practice is to wear it on the Seemanta or the parting of the hair.

The [Lalita Sahsranama from Brahmanda Purana](https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/brahmandapurana/bookview.php?chapnum=31) uses the words "Seemanta Sindhuri" which clearly indicates the exact place where one should wear the Sindhoor.

> Shruti **seemanta Sindoori** kruta paadaabja dhulikaa,
>  Sakalaagama
>   Sandoha Shukti Samputa Mouktikaa/
>
> The particles of your Lotus feet tuns red as S induri which adorns the
>   foreheads of virtuous women;

From a dictionary you can check the meaning of the word [Seemanta](http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?tran_input=sImanta&direct=se&script=hk&link=yes&mode=3) which basically here means the "parting of the hair".
So, the lady should part the hair and put it there. If parting the hair is not possible for some reasons then I don't know what is ideal for her to do.

Answer (score 3):

Having no obvious part in the hair is not a problem. I have seen many women wear Sindur at different places than the part.

Women wear Sindur based on their preferences. I have seen women apply Sindur just at the part, and places other than the part.

If a person wishes to wear Sindur, it is sufficient just to wear it. Not wearing at the part does not do any harm.

> Sindoor is traditionally applied at the beginning or completely along the parting-line of a woman’s hair (also called maang in Hindi or "Seemandarekha" in Sanskrit) or as a dot on the forehead.

From [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sindoor).

So, see, if wearing Sindur in Bindi form is also accepted (Sindur for married women only), then there will be no problem in applying it in some place else.

There is no hard and fast rule that you have to wear it in a particular place.

If there is no clear parting on a woman's head, then she can either choose it to wear on the middle of her face i.e. in straight line to her nose or she can wear it where she chooses. But remember, it should not be too far away from the middle of her forehead.

Answer (score 1):

At "Seemandarekha"!

Seemandarekha is nothing but the parting-line of a woman’s hair (also called maang in Hindi). Seemandarekha is sanskrit word, means Maang.

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sindoor)